# .Net PostgreSQL Connection String

Tags: .net, database, postgresql, connection-string

I am using PostgreSQL in a project I am working on, and one of the queries is timing out.  I need to increase the timeout on the database connection, but since I am using my DAO through a complex wrapper to Active Record and NHibernate, I am not able to adjust the timeout of the command object - so I am hoping you can change the timeout through the connection string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one:

Provider=PostgreSQL OLE DB Provider;Data Source=myServerAddress;location=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;password=myPassword;timeout=1000;

Just replace the obvious parts (myUsername, myServerAddress, etc...) with your stuff.

Also, for your reference, this site will give you connection string templates for pretty much any database on earth for pretty much any way you need to use it:

http://www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 9):

[Npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html)-native connection string:

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Userid=u;Password=p;Protocol=3;SSL=false;Pooling=false;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=20;Timeout=15;SslMode=Disable;Database=test"
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it: CommandTimeout=20;Timeout=15;

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to optimize the query?  Optimizing is the best choice over increasing timeouts.

Comment: I second this, explain analyse is your friend. Look for slow sequential scans and a poor join order, etc.