# Unable to retrieve metadata connecting MVC3 EF with Postgres 9.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to connect my MVC3 project with a database in Postgres 9.1, I've follow this links: [info1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211475/entity-framework-postgresql), [info2](http://ud-csharp.blogspot.com/2010/02/entity-framework-con-postgresql.html), [info3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464131/net-postgresql-connection-string) and for the look of it, I only need the string connection in order to create a Controller.

I have the reference to the `Mono.Security` and `Npgsql` .dll, I add them to the Assembly

I'm using this `connectionString`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestPostgreSQLContext"         
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TestPostgreSQL.csdl|res://*/Models.TestPostgreSQL.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestPostgreSQL.msl;provider=Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=testPostgres;persist security info=True;user id=postgres;password=123456;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**Code markup:**

```
public TestPostgreSQLContext() : base("name=TestPostgreSQLContext", "TestPostgreSQLContext")
{            
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}
public TestPostgreSQLContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "TestPostgreSQLContext")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}
public TestPostgreSQLContext(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "TestPostgreSQLContext")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}
```

**Here's an more graphical idea:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you declare Npgsql as a registered provider, in your app's config file or inside machine.config? (see [this official Npgsql documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ef6/)